# Identifying PROCESSENTRY32 Members' Variables

Tags: winapi, memory, hexdump

I have a memory dump with PROCESSENTRY32 structure at memory address 0x0012FC20. The task is to identify the values of the PROCESSENTRY32 member variables. I know that the first member - DWORD dwSize, refers to the first 32 bits, or 8 hex characters, of the dump, so it should be 0X00000128 or 296 bytes.
Does anyone know how do I find the rest of the values? The memory dump is displayed below.

Thanks a lot!

`````
0012FC28  6C 06 00 00 00 00 00 00  l......
0012FC30  00 00 00 00 15 00 00 00  .......
0012FC38  1C 06 00 00 0D 00 00 00  ......
0012FC40  00 00 00 00 77 69 6E 6C  ....winl
0012FC48  6F 67 6F 6E 2E 65 78 65  ogon.exe
0012FC50  00 73 73 5D 00 00 00 00  .ss]....
0012FC58  10 05 15 00 00 00 00 00  .....
0012FC60  00 00 00 00 3F 00 3F 00  ....?.?.
0012FC68  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ........
0012FC70  B4 21 91 7C 00 00 00 00  ¥!ë|....
0012FC78  00 00 00 00 00 00 15 00  .......
0012FC80  CB A3 91 7C B8 FC 12 00  À£ë|∏¸.
0012FC88  D7 F2 96 7C 00 00 15 00  ◊Úñ|...
0012FC90  00 00 00 00 68 2C 15 00  ....h,.
0012FC98  00 00 15 00 70 2C 15 00  ...p,.
0012FCA0  B4 FC 12 00 18 FD 12 00  ¥¸.˝.
0012FCA8  20 E9 90 7C 00 00 34 00   Èê|..4.
0012FCB0  AC FA 12 00 00 00 00 00  ¨˙.....
0012FCB8  EC FE 12 00 20 E9 90 7C  Ï˛. Èê|
0012FCC0  00 A0 91 7C FF FF FF FF  .†ë|ˇˇˇˇ
0012FCC8  FA 9F 91 7C 0C 9C 91 7C  ˙üë|.úë|
0012FCD0  00 00 34 00 60 00 00 40  ..4.`..@
0012FCD8  DB 01 91 7C 08 00 00 00  €ë|...
0012FCE0  00 00 00 00 A6 00 00 00  ....¶...
0012FCE8  00 00 00 00 86 BA 80 7C  ....Ü∫Ä|
0012FCF0  FF FF FF FF 00 00 00 00  ˇˇˇˇ....
0012FCF8  20 02 00 00 68 2C 15 00   ..h,.
0012FD00  00 00 15 00 4D 3C 86 7C  ...M<Ü|
0012FD08  00 00 00 00 18 FD 01 01  ....˝
0012FD10  C8 FC 12 00 00 00 00 00  »¸.....
0012FD18  00 FE 12 00 20 E9 90 7C  .˛. Èê|
0012FD20  E8 05 97 7C FF FF FF FF  Ëó|ˇˇˇˇ
0012FD28  C4 05 97 7C FC BA 94 7C  ƒó|¸∫î|
0012FD30  00 00 15 00 61 00 00 50  ...a..P
0012FD38  CB A3 91 7C 00 00 15 00  À£ë|...
0012FD40  70 2C 15 00 60           p,.````
`````

Comment: Use a debugger. WinDbg provides the [`dt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/dt--display-type-) command for that purpose.

Comment: Have you actually looked at the definition of [`PROCESSENTRY32`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/tlhelp32/ns-tlhelp32-processentry32) yet? It should be trivial to identify the values once you know where to look for them. Hint: they follow tne`DWORD dwSize` sequentially.

Comment: @RemyLebeau aha, got it. But would in this case the size of each member be the same - 32 bits? Sorry for being so dumb, I'm a very-very new to all this.

Comment: DWORD - 32 bits, ULONG_PTR - 32 or 64 bits, depending on the process, LONG - 32 bits, CHAR - 8 bits.

Comment: @tleilax A `DWORD` is always 32 bits in size, yes. See [Windows Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types) and [The New Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/the-new-data-types) on MSDN.

Comment: Note that you said the struct begins at memory address 0x0012FC20, but the dump you have shown starts at 0x0012FC28, so you are missing the first 8 bytes of the struct.

Comment: @JonathanPotter thanks so very much! Indeed, I should  have looked carefully through the data types.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks a million! I had all of this in my lecture notes, but only after your comment it started all making sense. And I did miss the first line from the hex dump, so you saved me here as well 